# Where are files written to in R?

Tags: r

If I use the write method, where will these files be written?  Example:

```
write(results, file="myFile.csv", ncolumns=1)
```

I don't specify a full path so I assume it's writing to some default directory.  I checked program files, but it's not there.  Suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you type from within your R session:

```
getwd()
```

You should be able to retrieve your current working directory, that's the place where the files should be saved to.

Comment: Which you can change with - amazingly - setwd("some/path/here")

Answer (score 2):

You can also choose to set your workspace to a location of your desire:

```
setwd('C:/Users/.../Documents/R/Scripts')
```

Files you save will automatically be written to this new location.